# How can I calculate the mean and standard deviation of a column in a data frame using the dplyr package?

Tags: r, dplyr

An Example:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10))
mean(data$x)
sd(data$x)
```

And it gives me an error. Why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't involve `dplyr` but it should not give an error.  You'll have to provide more details. You can try `data %>%  summarise(across(x, list(mean, sd)))`

Comment: without more detail such as the error message it's hard to say.  I get no error when running your code as written here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is running perfectly. However, I still want to give you the dplyr solution that I find most intuitive.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(x = rnorm(10)) %>%
  summarise(sd= sd(x),
            mean= mean(x))
#>          sd        mean
#> 1 0.8055597 -0.01786294
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>